# form enctype="multipart/form-data" returning contentType null in JSP RAD environment

Tags: jsp, file-upload, enctype

I'm following an example to do FileUpload on JSP page on this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm It looks pretty straightforward and I'm able to call the uploadFile.jsp to habdle the upload except that the request.getContentType() is returning null. Seems like the enctype="multipart/form-data" or encoding="multipart/form-data" is not setting the content type correctly. Here's the form tag in my jsp:

```
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload:<br/>
<form name="uploadform" method="post" encoding="multipart/form-data" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" /><br />
<input type="button" class="button1" value="Upload File" onClick="submitFileUpload();" />
</form>
```

And here's the snippet from the uploadFile.jsp where I'm getting null:
String contentType = request.getContentType();

I'm using JSP in RAD environment and this doesn't seem to work in either IE 10 or CHrome. I've searched extensivley on this error but couldn't find any reason why this may be happening. Looks like it works for most people. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I see you deviated from the tutorial where they have

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

you have

```
<input type="button" class="button1" value="Upload File" onClick="submitFileUpload();" />
```

Why?  If you're trying to do Ajax, there's your problem.  Setting the encoding type on the form isn't going to help you if you're then not actually using the form but using Ajax.

You should post the definition for the javascript function `submitFileUpload`.

On that part you probably should follow the tutorial to the letter.  But on another point you should deviate: You should use a Servlet not JSP to process the upload in the backend. Also, it would be a good idea to look at the examples on [Apache Commons Fileupload's own site](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload) because some methods may change in newer versions of the library.